# Div full height of container / body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this layout:

```
HEADER

DIV#1 | DIV#2

FOOTER
```

I want to `DIV#1` and `DIV#2` to be full height of the page.

I've tried to set height of `DIV#1` to 100%, as well as `body,html` height to 100%.

This is the result:

[image: Example]

As you can see, DIV#1 and DIV#2 are not full height (down to the footer..)

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="col-xs-2" id="sidemenu" style="background: red;">
    sidemenu div#1<br />
    sidemenu div#1
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-10" style="background: black;">
    content div#2<br />
    content div#2
    </div>


</div><!--/container-->
```

And the css..

```
  #sidemenu{
        border-right: 3px solid #F4F4F4;
        height: 100%;
    }
    html {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      /* Margin bottom by footer height */
      margin-bottom: 60px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
      height: 100%;
    }
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
    background-color: #e5ecf1;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    color: #7f8e99;
    padding: 30px 50px;
}
```

Comment: @mrida On which element?

Comment: You shouldn't be setting your footer to absolute position

Comment: you also need to set `height: 100%;` for `.container` and `html` both. post .container styles and div#1 and div#2 styles as well for better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` with `bottom: 0;` to pull the div the full height.

Comment: I have added this to #sidemenu, but then DIV#2 is getting a bit messed up - it will "overlap" with div#1

Comment: You will need to add a `margin-left` on DIV#2 with a value the same as the width of the `#sidemenu`

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should be like:

```
<headerdiv with specific height></headerdiv>
<sidediv with specific height></sidediv>
<footerdiv with specific height></footerdiv>
```

Comment: Specific height is not a good idea, since every window may be resized. But I agree that CSS sucks so badly that sometimes a bad idea end up becoming a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1st thing is to have html & body @ 100% height. Then, you need to make a wrapper of the elements you want to have a set height, to this height & assign `box-size:border-box;` and 100% height to the elements.

As per your example, something like this:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="col-xs-2 fh" id="sidemenu" style="background: red;">
sidemenu div#1<br />
sidemenu div#1
</div>

<div class="col-xs-10 fh" style="background: black;">
content div#2<br />
content div#2
</div>


</div><!--/container-->
```

and it's css

```
html, body {height:100%}
.container {height:100%;box-size:border-box;}
.fh {box-size:border-box;height:100%}
#sidemenu{
        border-right: 3px solid #F4F4F4;
        height: 100%;
    }
    html {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      /* Margin bottom by footer height */
      margin-bottom: 60px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
      height: 100%;
    }
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
    background-color: #e5ecf1;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    color: #7f8e99;
    padding: 30px 50px;
}
```

and [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/5J5vT/1/) to see it working